# The index page of Node.js does not read css or javascript files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html

It runs on Mac.

All files are in **Library/WebServer/Documents/**.

When I run node **index.js**, the code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> returns: {

   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

 }
```

However, if I open the html file, it reads everything.

What is the ugly bug behind?

Comment: a piece of code: link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"

Comment: Could you pls provide the code inside the `index.js` file? Else its hard to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inclued these resource before using them.

You can do it as : `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

'public'is folder where you will have static content like images/JS/CSS.

For more information visit : http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I learned basic of node from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ and also from express js official site

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Documents')));`
This will allow Node to serve all the files in that folder, such as CSS files or other things referenced in your HTML

I would recommend putting everything to be served(HTML, CSS, JS)in a public folder which you could pass to the above middleware.

In the above function, keep __dirname as that because it is a global variable that refers to the root director of the application